# Is a schedulable unit of CPU time slice process or thread?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, cpu-architecture, scheduling

**I want to clarify whether "a schedulable unit of CPU time slice" is "process" or "thread" (kernel managed thread)**. What I mean by "schedulable unit of CPU time slice" is the unit which CPU scheduler of an operating system allocates CPU time slice.

According to "[Short-term scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing))" in wikipedia, process is used to refer the schedulable unit.

> "This scheduler can be preemptive, implying that it is capable of forcibly removing **processes** from a CPU when it decides to allocate that CPU to another **process**"

Also, according to "[Time slice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing))" in wikepedia,

> "The scheduler is run once every time slice to choose the next **process** to run."

Also, according to "[Thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing))" in wikepedia,

> "a **process** is a unit of resources, while a **thread** is a unit of **scheduling** and execution"

According to "[Processes and Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/processes-and-threads)" in microsoft docs,

> "A **thread** is the basic unit to which the operating system allocates processor time."

According to "[Is thread scheduling done by the CPU, kernel, or both?](https://www.quora.com/Is-thread-scheduling-done-by-the-CPU-kernel-or-both)" in quora,

> "The CPU (hardware) just carries out instructions. The CPU itself has no concept of threads or scheduling, although there may be features in the CPU that support them.

> "The operating system kernel (a set of instructions, aka software) executes on the CPU (hardware). A scheduling algorithm in the kernel of the operating system chooses which **thread** to execute next, and directs the CPU to begin executing the next instruction in that chosen **thread**".

Comment: Don't seek authoritative answers on Wikipedia. There used to be a time, not very long ago, when threads didn't exist in any major operating system. Some of us still have books on the shelf from back in those days. Maybe whoever wrote those first two Wikipedia articles got their ideas from some of those same books.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Solomon Slow. I haven't thought of the possibility that the statement could be written by the time when thread didn't existed or the writer of statement could have written based on reference of that time. I really appreciate your comment. Also, I thought of wikipedia contents are close to professional because contents would likely be edited if there is something wrong. But, like you said, I should seek authoritative answers from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Clarification*: my understanding of "a schedulable unit of CPU time slice" is "a unit that can be scheduled during a given CPU time slice" (since if "schedulable unit" would be a time then the question does not make much sense to me).

Based on this, put it shortly, **"a schedulable unit of CPU time slice" for a given logical core can be seen as a software thread** (more specifically its execution context composed of registers and process information).

---

Operating systems scheduler operates on **tasks**. Tasks can be threads, processes, or other unusual structure (eg. dataflows).

Modern mainstream operating system mainly schedule **threads** on processing units (typically *hardware threads* also called *logical cores*). You can get more information about how the Windows scheduler works in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/about-processes-and-threads). The documentation explicitly states:

> A thread is the entity within a process that can be scheduled for execution

On Linux, the default scheduler, [CFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler), operates on [task](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h#L728) (ie. `task_struct` data structure). Tasks can be a thread, a group of threads or a process. This was done that way so to make the scheduler more generic and also because this scheduler was designed long ago, when processors had only 1 core and people focused on processes rather than thread. The multi-core era since caused applications to use a lot of threads so to use available cores. As a result, nowadays, it is generally threads that are actually scheduled AFAIK. This is explained in the famous research paper [The Linux Scheduler: a Decade of Wasted Cores](https://people.ece.ubc.ca/sasha/papers/eurosys16-final29.pdf) (which also explain a bit how the CFS operate regarding the target processor).

Note that the term "process" can sometime refer to a thread since threads are sometime called "lightweight processes" and basic processes are sometime called "heavy processes". Processes can even be a generic term for both heavy and lightweight processes (ie. threads and actual processes). This is a very confusing terminology and a misuse of language (like the term "processors" sometimes used for cores). In practice, this is often not a problem in a specific context since threads and processes may be used interchangeably though (in such a case, people should use a generic term like "tasks").

As for "a schedulable unit of CPU time slice" this is a bit more complex. A simple and naive answer is: *a thread* (it is definitively not processes alone). That being said, a thread is a software-defined concept (like processes). It is basically a stack, few registers, and a parent process (with possibly some meta-information and a TLS space). CPUs does not operate directly on such data structure. CPU does not have a concept of thread stack for example (it is just a section of the virtual process memory like any other). They just need an execution context which is composed of registers and a process configuration (in [protected mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode)). For sake of simplicity, we can say that they execute threads. Mainstream modern x86 processors are very complex, and each core is often able to run multiple threads at the same time. This is called [simultaneous multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) (aka. Hyper-Threading for Intel processors). x86 physical cores are typically composed of two logical threads (ie. hardware threads) that can each execute a software threads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jérôme Richard. Yes, what I meant by "schedulable unit" is the unit that can be scheduled by OS, but which is being executed by CPU, or each core of CPU, during a given CPU time slice.

Answer (score 1):

I think your misunderstanding is actually a misunderstanding of what the English words mean in this context.

A time slice is a *period of time*.  Maybe it is a fraction of a second.  Maybe a few seconds.

Threads and processes are effectively *tasks* that the computer is going to perform.  (I am simplifying here.  The notion of a task has multiple meanings, even in the IT context.  And on a modern OS, a process is actually a collection of threads that share the same virtual memory address space.)

The CPU<sup>1</sup> or processor is hardware that will *run* a (native) thread.  A typical computer will have multiple CPUs.  However, each CPU in a computer can only run one thread *at a time*.

The operating system therefore needs to schedule each of the threads it knows about to run on a specific CPU.  The part of the operating system that does this is called the *scheduler*.

If there are more threads to run than CPUs to run them, the scheduler will typically schedule a thread to a CPU for a fixed period of time; i.e a *time slice*.  When the thread's time slice has elapsed, the scheduler will suspend it and put it back into the queue, and then schedule a different thread to run on the CPU.

The metaphor is that we are "slicing up" the available compute time on the CPUs and sharing the slices between the threads that need it.

<sup>1 - There is some disagreement over what "CPU" actually means.  I am taking the view that it refers to what it commonly called a "core".  Intel confusingly introduced the marketing term<sup>2</sup> "hyperthread" which refers to a feature in which the physical hardware of a "core" can run as two independent instruction executors.  However, in hyperthread mode, the OS scheduler will *typically* treat the hyperthreads as if they are distinct cores, so this is not pertinent to your question.

2 - The actual concept behind hyperthreads goes back to the 1960s, before Intel even existed as a company; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_processor.</sup>

---

So the answer to your question:

> I want to clarify whether "a schedulable unit of CPU time slice" is "process" or "thread" (kernel managed thread).

A time slice is a schedulable unit of CPU time.

A time slice is neither a process or a thread.  Indeed that doesn't even make sense because "process" and "thread" are not time.

---

I concur with @Solomon Slow's comment.  Wikipedia is not authoritative.  But the real problem is that different pages are written and edited by different people over time, and they often use IT terminology inconsistently.

My advice would be to find and read One good textbook on (modern) operating system design and architecture.  A well-written text book *should* be self-consistent in its use of terminology.

Comment: The definition of "CPU" is not commonly well defined for multicore processors. AFAIK, the most common definition is that a CPU is the main processor of of a computer so it contains one of multiple cores. This is the definition I saw in textbooks like the one of [Victor Eijkhout](https://theartofhpc.com) and university lectures. The [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU) considers a processor core as an individual CPU. Thus, a multicore processor can contain multiple CPUs. The definition mismatches and I think it is better to always precise which one we consider.

Comment: What is even more confusing is that the CPU page of Wikipedia show image of a "Intel Core i5 CPU" which is a multicore processor. Even better: the French translation of the CPU page of Wikipedia redirect users to "Processeur" (meaning "Processor" in English), but the term Processor/Processeur is better defined and I think nearly every one agree with the fact that modern microprocessors contains >=1 cores and are one kind of processor. Some pages of Wikipedia also point out this confusion and specifically define the term CPU. What a mess... I fully agree with you for the inconsistency!

Comment: "hyperthreading" is an Intel trademark, but they didn't invent the concept.  Generically, it's called [Simultaneous Multithreading (SMT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading), and has existed as a concept since 1968.  Alpha EV8 (in the 90s) was the first mainstream CPU with SMT, but it got cancelled; Intel hired some of that design team to work on Pentium 4, which ended up being the first modern commercial CPU with SMT.  It's now fairly widespread.  The generic name includes the word "thread", so that wasn't unique to Intel's branding.

Comment: RISC-V documentation invented the useful term "hart", aka "hardware thread".  An execution context that a software thread can execute on, however it's implemented.  (A physical core alone, or an SMT thread of a physical core, or slots of a barrel process, or switch-on-stall, or whatever.)  So instead of saying i7-6700k is a 4c8t CPU, we'd say 4 physical cores implementing 8 harts (or 4 if you disable hyperthreading in the BIOS).

Comment: Either way, yes, SMT logical cores look to the OS like real cores: hyperthreading support in an OS isn't the ability to start up those extra "hardware threads" (that already happens the same way as detecting all CPU cores in a system).  It's the ability to *detect* which cores share physical cores, and make smart scheduling decisions (like to run tasks on cores that don't compete for the same physical core.)

Comment: Well ... if you want to argue about who invented the concept, I reckon CDC has precedence.  In their CDC 6000 mainframes (1964) the multiple PPUs all shared a single set of ALUs etc.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_processor

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stephen C. My question was actually "The CPU or processor is hardware that will run a [___]" <- what is the thing that fits to blank? I thought "thread" fits to the blank, but statements containing "process" at that blank resulted from web search, then I got confused.

Comment: That is NOT what you wrote in your question.   Your question says (and I quote) *"I want to clarify whether "a schedulable unit of CPU time slice" is "process" or "thread" (kernel managed thread). What I mean by "schedulable unit of CPU time slice" is the unit which CPU scheduler of an operating system allocates CPU time slice."*.   If you want to ask a different question, post a new one!!

Comment: But the answer is it depends on which definitions of 'thread' and 'process' you are using.  Originally, operating systems didn't support multiple (native) threads in a process, so "process" would fit.  These days, operating systems typically support multiple threads per process, so "thread" is a better fit.

Comment: Yes I said "I want to clarify whether "a schedulable unit of CPU time slice" is "process" or "thread" (kernel managed thread). What I mean by "schedulable unit of CPU time slice" is the unit which CPU scheduler of an operating system allocates CPU time slice.". From this sentence, I want to clarify [schedulable unit] / [schedulable unit] that is scheduled by [CPU scheduler] / [schedulable unit] which the [CPU scheduler] allocates [CPU time slice]. The expression is come up in this sense.

Comment: I'm really sorry about my misinterpretable wording.

Answer (score 0):

A time slice is a unit of time, for example 10 ms in a traditional Linux kernel built with HZ=100 (100 timer interrupts per second).  After a task has been running for that long on a CPU core, the kernel regains control on that CPU and calls `schedule()` to decide what task this CPU core should run next; the task it was already running, or a different task.

The scheduler can also run earlier if an external interrupt comes in, especially near the end of the current timeslice: if there's a higher-priority task that's now waiting for a CPU, e.g. after waiting for I/O or after a `sleep()` system call ended, it makes sense for the OS to schedule it onto this core, instead of finishing the time-slice of whatever CPU-bound task was interrupted.

---

**Task** is a useful word for the things the scheduler has to pick from.  Without implying separate process or threads within a process, and also leaving room for kernel tasks like a Linux interrupt handler "bottom half" that aren't threads or processes.

Every thread of a process needs to get scheduled separately to execute on a CPU core (if it's not blocked).

The articles you found about scheduling processes is using the simplifying assumption that each process is single-threaded.

Or they're assuming a 1:n threading model, where the OS is only aware of one task for the whole process, and multithreading is done in user-space, "[green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads)" instead of native threads.  Most mainstream OSes these days use a 1:1 threading model, where every C++ or Java thread is a separately schedulable task visible to the OS, although n:m models are possible where you have multiple OS-scheduled tasks, but not as many as you have high-level-language threads.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Peter Cordes. Yes, task is the term that represents, but in abstraction. I wanted to know a little more detail which is shown in your sentence. What is the thing that "get scheduled separately to execute on a CPU core", you've said "Every thread of a process" but before getting your answer I've seen some articles stated process, which is why I posted this question.

Comment: @YoonSeokOH: Read the next paragraph, I put it there exactly to explain that disconnect.  The articles you've seen talking about process-scheduling aren't thread-aware: they're assuming every process has only one thread, at least as far as the OS is concerned.  That's not how modern systems work.